# Empty string syntax inside vimrc defined via nix home-manager

Tags: vimrc, nix

I want to use home-manager to declare my vim configuration inside a nix-expression with the extraConfig option.
I'm trying to run the example .vimrc configuration from coc.nvim and one line reads:

> set statusline^=%{coc#status()}%{get(b:,'coc_current_function','')}

Inside a minimal home.nix I set it like this:

```
{ config, pkgs, ... }:

{
  # Let Home Manager install and manage itself.
  programs.home-manager.enable = true;

  home.packages = [ 
    pkgs.nodejs
  ];

programs.vim = { 
    enable = true;
    plugins = [
      pkgs.vimPlugins.coc-nvim
    ];
    extraConfig = ''
" Add status line support, for integration with other plugin, checkout `:h coc-status`
set statusline^=%{coc"status()}%{get(b:,'coc_current_function','')}
      '';
  };
}
```

Unfortunately the empty vim string closes the multi-line nix string and leaves `home-manager build switch` with:

```
error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ';', at /home/demo/.config/nixpkgs/home.nix:18:66
```

I already tried replacing `''` with `""` inside the get-function, but vim doesn't like that:

```
E540: Unclosed expression sequence: statusline^=%{coc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the two single quotes ('') indicates the end of the indented strings, so to use them within an indented string you need to escape them:

> Since ${ and '' have special meaning in indented strings, you need a way to quote them. $ can be escaped by prefixing it with '' (that is, two single quotes), i.e., ''$. **'' can be escaped by prefixing it with ', i.e., '''**. - source: https://nixos.org/nix/manual/